# Android TextView.setText triggers fragment onActivityCreated

Tags: android

I don't get it, why would simple text change trigger another fragment redraw.

Changing something in layout dynamically triggers whole activity recreation? O_o

Have i missed something? There was nothing related to this in the docs.

How to solve this?

Should i add some flag, to check whether some fragment in activity need redraw, when this redraw is called?

I'm using Runnable and Handler timer implementation to update timer in TextView each second.

Comment: The fragment is probably a sibling to the text view( or sibling to the parent of text view) and the fragment is sized relatively to it. When the size of one changes, the other is redrawn.

Comment: Well timer is above fragment, but it's inside RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout have wrap_contents, maybe i should set fixed size for it? What solution?

Comment: I have moved that fragment on the top and anyway it's triggering it.

Comment: Changing the order of placement wouldn't matter as resizing a child leads to re-drawing of all the children of the changed-view's parent. I'm not sure if making the size fixed would solve your problem, either. Let me know if it does.

Comment: So where do i need to move it?

Comment: make it a non-sibling. Move it into another parent layout. Make sure the parents are not dynamically resizable.